# Send something to the webservice in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit, appdelegate

When my app goes to the background I want to send a final request to the webservice. But it seems that it not waits until the request is finished. Can somebody help me with this?

This is what I do

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    NSMutableArray *arrFavorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    GenkonStageDataModel *model = [[GenkonStageDataModel alloc]init];
    arrFavorites = [model getAllFavorites];

    API *api = [API new];

  //create dictionary values

   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:uuid,@"uuId",strFav,@"pushFavorits",favPush,@"push", nil];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [api mapGetData];
    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/webservice/apnsusers/update" parameters:dict
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                NSError *error = nil;
                                BOOL success = [objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext  save:&error];
                                if (!success) RKLogWarning(@"Failed saving managed object context: %@", error);

                                NSLog(@"updated favorites");
                            }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                 message:[error localizedDescription]
                                 delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                  [alert show];
                                NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                            }];
    NSError *error2 = nil;
    [context save:&error2];


}
```

Comment: You only have microseconds of CPU time as the application is being backgrounded and the fact you're trying to do block functions (i.e. not trivial and/or quick, in terms of the CPU), it only makes sense you're not seeing success.

Comment: How would you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `applicationWillResignActive:` and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` methods of the app delegate protocol should not be used to send requests to the server. This methods should be use to save the current state of the application. 
So maybe you should save the data/params(shared prefs or core data) that you want to send to the server and perform the request in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` or `applicationWillEnterForeground:` depending on your needs.

Comment: This is my situation: people can add some favorite artists. I save them with core data. But I need to now the server about this also. Becasue he is sending push notifications for each favorites. I can say to send request on each change on favorites. But then I'm going to send a lot of request quickly after each other. So I was thinking  to send the whole list when the application goes to the background.

Comment: @Stef Geelen Well, you can't do this request in the app delegate methods that are called when the app is going to background or it is going to an inactive state (phone call) because the methods are not waiting for long timing code execution (kind of logic because the system wants to close your app and). So I think you should change your approach in this situation, maybe do a batch request with the favorites when the user finish selecting the favorites, but this may cause inconsistent data (user puts the app in bg when selecting favorites). So, best way, foreach favorite one request ;)